# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Application startup error:

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

When I run `gcloud app deploy` I get error response 9. The error message I get is

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
```

**app.js**

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'myid';

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
});

// The kind for the new entity
const kind = 'Task';
// The name/ID for the new entity
const name = 'sampletask1';
// The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);

// Prepares the new entity
const task = {
    key: taskKey,
    data: {
        description: 'Buy milk',
    },
};

// Saves the entity
datastore
    .save(task)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Saved ${task.key.name}: ${task.data.description}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "first-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "First program using cloud datastore",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"node app.js",
    "deploy":"gcloud app deploy",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ragav",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/datastore": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

Please help me, I am trying to learn deploying my app server on GCP. Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved the issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the example you show, please follow the [instructions in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries):

1. Download the credentials `JSON` file and create an environment variable that points to this file:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/your/credential-file.json"`

2. Copy the code in, i.e., `sample.js` file and run `node sample.js`.

On the other hand, if you want to deploy a `nodejs` app, you'll need `express.js` or any other framework.

I did the following with the help of `express.js`:

I wrapped your code in a function called `saveEntity(datastore)`

Then I added [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) to the app like in the [sample nodejs app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart) and from there I called saveEntity(datastore):

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    saveEntity(datastore);
    res.status(200).send("Entity saved").end();
}); 

// [START listen]
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
// [END listen]
// [END app]

module.exports = app;
```

The complete result is this:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
//Needed to create the node app
const express = require('express')

const app = express();

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'my-project-id';

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
});

function saveEntity(datastore){
    // The kind for the new entity
    const kind = 'JulyTask';
    // The name/ID for the new entity
    const name = 'sampletask1';
    // The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
    const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);

    // Creates entity data
    const task = {
        name: 'Learn something',
        status: 'In progress',
        description: 'Friday 6 July'
    }

    //With the data and the key, create the entity
    const entity = {
        key: taskKey,
        data: task
    }

    // Saves the entity
    datastore
        .upsert(entity)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Saved:\n' + JSON.stringify(entity));
            return true;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
            return false;
        });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    saveEntity(datastore);
    res.status(200).send("Entity saved").end();
}); 

// [START listen]
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
// [END listen]
// [END app]

module.exports = app;
```

The `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "first-application",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "First program using cloud datastore",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "deploy": "gcloud app deploy",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Ragav",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/datastore": "^1.4.1",
        "express": "^4.16.3"
    }
}
```

Also you should know that this is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/upgrading#upgrading_to_the_flexible_environment):

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

You could do this instead:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: my-service-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. At the loggin it also said:

```
ERROR: build step 0
```

I solved it deleting two of the buckets on the project I was trying to deploy. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/ and delete the buckets that start with:

```
stagging....
artifact...
```

After doing this you can deploy again

I am not sure what was the exact cause of the problem as the error is not clear nor the documentation.

My guess is that there is a problem with storage limit but as I said I can't be sure.