# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy two services on App Engine (GCP) under the same project. I already deployed the first service (default) using the following **yaml file**:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

This first service was deployed correctly. A couple of days after, I tried to deploy a new app under a **different service name**:

```
service: test-app
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

This second app is the initial "blank" app that you have when creating a new React app. However, I am running into the following error:

```
Updating service [test-app] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
```

I tried to remove the resources of each file (after finding this solution online) but it didn't solve my problem. I can't find a lot of documentation online for this issue. From the logs that I can access on GCP, it seems that the second service is built correctly.

Please let me know if you have any idea of the problem.

With the verbosity set to debug, I have:

```
Updating service [test-app] (this may take several minutes)...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/***/operations/***-***-***-***-***] not complete. Waiting to retry.

Updating service [test-app] (this may take several minutes)...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/***/operations/***-***-***-***-***] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "user": "***",
        "target": "***",
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
        "insertTime": "2020-04-14T17:12:37.283Z",
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion"
    },
    "done": true,
    "name": "***",
    "error": {
        "message": "Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED> 

test-app@0.1.0 start /app> 
react-scripts start

[34m\u2139\u001b[39m \u001b[90m\uff62wds\uff63\u001b[39m: Project is running at http://172.
[34m\u2139\u001b[39m \u001b[90m\uff62wds\uff63\u001b[39m: webpack output is served from 
[34m\u2139\u001b[39m \u001b[90m\uff62wds\uff63\u001b[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
[34m\u2139\u001b[39m \u001b[90m\uff62wds\uff63\u001b[39m: 404s will fallback to 
Starting the development server...",
        "code": 9
    }
}
Updating service [test-app] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
```

Comment: I don't think that AppEngine configurations related to this issue. As I understand you are deploying your app from Docker file, can you please post full 'gcloud deploy' command. Also, can you please run 'gcloud deploy' command with the '--verbosity=debug' (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) flag?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jaroslav. I am using my commands in Visual Studio. I tried with gcloud app deploy and with gcloud app deploy test-app.yaml after renaming the second yaml file. With the verbosity set to debug, I have the results presented in the edited post.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to find any solution for the issue, and by now I found this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923461/setting-up-app-yaml-file-for-node-js-and-react-js-deployment-to-app-engine